# Визуальные атрибуты команд в чате

Tags: java, minecraft

Я ни где не могу найти гайд или туториал чтобы в чате отображались подсказки при вводе команды.

Пример:
[image: Пример]

Как в том же WorldEdit когда вводишь //set и там выбираешь блок